# EGit wrong parent after commit (Eclipse Git)

Tags: eclipse, git

Assuming I have a synchronized working copy, local Git repository and remote Git repository.
I'm not *totally* sure if the working copy and the local repository are really synchronized. But they do have the same files and I have "no changes" denoted between working copy and local repository.

My initial state of the repository looks like this (I'm working on a Branch called "GenerateContent"):

[image]

Now I make some changes to my working copy and commit them to the local "GenerateContent" branch.

Now the problem occurs: Instead of using the current commit-state as a parent, an earlier state is used as a parent. You can see this in the screenshot:

[image]

From this emerge many problems. For example I have to merge my changes with an older version.

This problem does occur only in EGit (Eclipse Git). When I do the same changes in eclipse, but do the commit from another software (SourceTree), then the tree stay's linear.

What do I do wrong in EGit? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you [file an EGit bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) for this and attach your sample repository? If you can't publish the repository, the output of `git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate` may help to understand the situation before and after the commit.